# Cannot add space from deleted Windows partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted, resize, unallocated

I recently found that 50 GB was simply not enough for Ubuntu and deleted the entire Windows partition to assign the space to Ubuntu. I can't resize the Ubuntu partition and it does not go over 50 GB (the original size). I have tried to reallocate it from a live Ubuntu disk, but there are still no changes.

Now I am stuck with 135 GB of unallocated space.

[image]

Comment: The space you want to use is *not* next to your Linux partitions.  You cannot 'expand' your Linux filesystem into empty space that the partition is not next to.  You will need to boot into a LiveUSB or Live environment, and then move your partitions around so that the empty space is at the end of your Linux partition, then you need to resize it to fill that space.  **This will take time, and you should have a backup of critical data you want to keep in case this fails, because any time partitions get moved it can break things badly.**

Comment: Please try and crop images when posting here. That image is enormous and the part we are interested in is very small. I have now done this for you, but please do it yourself next time. Huge images make the post slower to load and also make it harder to see the relevant information.

Comment: An alternative to what @ThomasWard suggested is to just use this as your home partition. You can mount it at `/home` and then you will have plenty of space for your personal stuff. Is that a workable solution for you or do you absolutely want a single, large partition?